# How do I even start sorting/getting data from a .txt file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So my task involves finding and printing the player name with the most games, shots etc and his name from a .txt file that looks like this;

```
Rk|Player|Age|Games|Minutes Played|Field Goals|Field Goal Attempts|3P Field Goals|3P Field Goal Attempts  
1|Quincy Acy|24|60|1110|126|278|12|47  
2|Jordan Adams|20|24|173|22|51|7|16  
...  
484|Cody Zeller|22|62|1487|172|373|1|1  
485|Tyler Zeller|25|74|1560|300|550|0|0
```

I was thinking about making empty lists and then filling them with for example "Games" and then pull the max value but I don't understand how to pull out the number of games.

Comment: No, bad idea. Use `pandas.read_csv` with `sep='|'`. It would be easier then to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's csv module.
Your code might look like this.

```
import csv

with open('games.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print "Player name: %s, Rank: %s" % (row['Player'], row['Rk'])
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for more details.